How to reshape a dataframe into wide format with specified column pairs
I have the following melted sample dataframe:
df_melted <- data.frame(ID = c(21, 21, 21, 21, 49, 49, 49, 49), instance = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), variable = c("causeofdeath", "deathdate", "dob", "gender", "causeofdeath", "deathdate", "deathdate", "causeofdeath"), value_temp = c("BLANK", "MM/DD/YYYY", "BLANK", "F", "BLANK", "BLANK", "MM/DD/YYYY", "BLANK"))


And the following mapping file that I want to eventually use to produce new values by using a left_join():
df_map <- data.frame(var_name_1 = c("causeofdeath", "causeofdeath", "dob"), val_1 = c("BLANK", "BLANK", "MM/DD/YYYY"), var_name_2 = c("deathdate", "deathdate", "gender"), val_2 = c("MM/DD/YYYY", "BLANK", "F"), new_var_name = c("ida", "idf", "ids"), new_val = c("T60", "T55", "T67"))


How can I reshape df_melted so that it is in the same particular arrangement as shown in df_map without making any assumptions about the order of the dataframe?, ie:

I have tried using pivot_wider() to no avail

pivot_wider(df_melted, names_from=variable, values_from=value_temp) would be the normal way to reshape your data. Is there some reason why you want to mix different variables within the same column? That would make it harder to analyse.

@Edward, I am mixing different variables within a column because my intention is to ultimately do a left join with df_map in order to get the new values. Is there a better way?

You can try pivot_wider after adding some auxiliary columns, e.g., p and grp
df_melted %>%
    mutate(p = rep(1:2, length.out = n()), grp = ceiling(row_number() / 2)) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = p,
        values_from = c(variable, value_temp),
        id_cols = c(ID, instance, grp),
        names_vary = "slowest"
    ) %>%
    select(-grp)

and you will obtain
# A tibble: 4 × 6
     ID instance variable_1   value_temp_1 variable_2   value_temp_2
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>
1    21        1 causeofdeath BLANK        deathdate    MM/DD/YYYY
2    21        1 dob          BLANK        gender       F
3    49        1 causeofdeath BLANK        deathdate    BLANK
4    49        2 deathdate    MM/DD/YYYY   causeofdeath BLANK


Can you explain the auxiliary columns? Don't they rely on df_melted already occurring in a specific order so that the correct variable pairs will land in the correct column?

@Andrea I assume every consecutive two rows forms a pair. p is the identifier of members within each pair, and grp indicates the pair numbers.

Is there an alternative without this assumption? I would like to somehow use df_map to create the layout because I cannot assume anything about the order of the data. Thank you

@Andrea could you show it in your question post?

I believe I updated it just now to add this

@Andrea how do you use df_map for df_melted to generate the desired output? I don't understand your logic here

since the mapping file shows the variables causeofdeath (value blank) side by side with deathdate (value MM/DD/YYYY) in the same row as a pair, I want the data to also have these values arranged in a row if they exist for a particular ID and instance (visit) if they occur. My ultimate goal is to eventually do a left_join with the mapping file to get the new_val
